# Spark Session failing to initialize - IsolatedClientLoader ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to initialize a spark session but for some weird reason, I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException while loading the classes for the Hive Metastore.

The traces seem to show that there is some isolation of the classloader for the Hive client and the Hive metastore implemented via a class called the IsolatedClientLoader, but i cant seem to figure out why.
When i started the jvm using `-verbose:class`, i noticed that the class which is not found is being loaded correctly into the jvm

Here is the stacktrace

```
- read from json save as parquet *** FAILED *** (1 second, 776 milliseconds)
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf when creating Hive client using classpath: file:/home/src/2.11/build/classes/java/test/, file:/home/src/2.11/build/classes/scala/test/
Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:221)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.loadClass(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:210)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  ...
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the jdk version being used to launch spark.
It seems that the version used i.e spark 2.3.2 with scala 2.11 is not supported with jdk 11.

Switching the compiling and execution to jdk 8 should fix the problem.

Interestingly, this problem does not occur with spark 3.0.2.
I was able to trace it down to the following piece of code that fixes the problem with jdk 11

`HiveUtils.scala`

```
val jars: Array[URL] = if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_9)) {
    // Do nothing. The system classloader is no longer a URLClassLoader in Java 9,
    // so it won't match the case in allJars. It no longer exposes URLs of
    // the system classpath
    Array.empty[URL]
  } else {
    val loadedJars = allJars(classLoader)
    // Verify at least one jar was found
    if (loadedJars.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Unable to locate hive jars to connect to metastore. " +
          s"Please set ${HIVE_METASTORE_JARS.key}.")
    }
    loadedJars
  }
```